# let $c>0$ and $a_{1} = (c/2)$, $a_{n+1} = \frac{c + a_{n}^2}{2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $c>0$ and $a_{1} = \frac{c}2$, $a_{n+1} = \frac{c + a_{n}^2}{2}$. Determine all $c$ for which the sequence converges . For such $c$ find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}$.

Could anyone help me please in solving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: okay I am so sorry @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: This has been asked before. Give me some time and I will find it.

Comment: ok i cannot find it, but it did appear a few days ago.

Comment: @xbh could you please tell me how to search for a question on this site ..... sometimes the title of the question differs from its real content?

Comment: Adding context to your Question will improve it.  For example, what makes this problem interesting to you (or difficult)?  If one cannot say all the $c$ for which the sequence converges, can one perhaps identify at least one $c$ for which it converges?  If the sequence converges, can one say something about its limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $a_{2} = \frac{c + a_{1}^2}{2}>a_1=\frac{c}{2}$, and for $n\geq 2$
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{c + a_{n}^2}{2}-\frac{c + a_{n-1}^2}{2}=\frac{(a_n-a_{n-1})(a_n+a_{n-1})}{2}>0.$$
So the sequence$\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing.
If the sequence is bounded, then the limit exists, suppose its limit is $a$, then it must satisfy $$a=\frac{c+a^2}{2}.$$
If this equation has solution($a=1\pm\sqrt{1-c}$), it must be $$0<c\leq 1.$$
When $c\in(0,1]$, we prove the sequence is bounded. By induction if $0<a_n<1-\sqrt{1-c}$ (you can check that $a_1<1-\sqrt{1-c}$), then 
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{c + a_{n}^2}{2}<\frac{c+(1-\sqrt{1-c})^2}{2}=1-\sqrt{1-c}.$$
So when $c\in(0,1]$, the limit is $1-\sqrt{1-c}$.

Comment: Why $a_{n} - a_{n-1}$ (in the second line after the last equality) must be positive?

Comment: $a_2-a_1>0$ implies $a_3-a_2>0$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the AM-GM inequality we get
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{c+a_n^2}2 \ge \sqrt{ca_n^2} = \sqrt{c}a_n$$

so if $a_n\to L \ge 0$, we get $L \ge \sqrt{c} L$, or $c \le 1$.

Also letting $n\to\infty$ in $a_{n+1} = \frac{c+a_n^2}2$ gives $L = \frac{c+L^2}2$ so $L = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-c}$. Since $c \le 1$, inductively we can prove that $a_n \le 1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ so $L \le 1$. Therefore $L = 1 -\sqrt{1-c}$ is the only candidate for the limit.

For any $c \in \langle 0,1]$ then inductively show that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ increases so it indeed converges to $1 -\sqrt{1-c}$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Solve $$l=\frac{c+l^2}{2}$$

to get a list of possible values of the limit (I'll leave it to you to see why this is true)

**Edit:** Look at the comments for mroe hints

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The main question is to find the values of $c$ for which the limit exists.

Comment: Yes, the values of $l$ depend on $c$. OP will have to solve a quadratic equation to get a list of possible values for $l$, depending on whether the equation has a solution and this equation is parametrised by $c$

Comment: @asdf But first of all you have to check for which $c$ the sequence converges. Otherwise $l$ does not exist.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Yes, in order for you to have a solution for  $l$, you need $l^2−2l+c=0$ to have a solution, i.e. you need $1−c≥0$. This is a necessary condition. Then you can apply the standard boundedness and monotenely increasing argument